# Which sentence is the appropriate one to express my wonder

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, punctuation

Suppose, someone knows me and quite surprisingly she is denying that she knows me infront of her friend. I **wonder** and start **asking** her about it. Which one would be the appropriate sentence?

I thought, because of *wonder*, 2 could be an option.

1. *You don't know me?*
2. *You don't know me!*
3. *Don't you know me?*

Comment: If you are **asking** her, (2) isn't a question (though the difference from (1) would only be in the intonation). Neither (1) nor (3) is 'inappropriate'.

Comment: But I thought, because of wonder, 2 could be an option. Does 3 mean " You know me" ? Is 2 same to 1 ? Is 1 grammatically correct?

Comment: With the exclamation mark you want to express your **astonishment** or **incredulity**. In English ***wonder*** is softer, gentler, it can express a quizzical nature, but it is not interrogative so the question mark nor the exclamation is not needed “*I wonder if he's thinking about me.*”

Comment: P.S You really should start casting some votes on the answers you receive. Your profile says you haven't cast one vote.

Comment: @Mari-LouA yeah , I also feel I should. Thank you for your suggestion. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comment, 1 and 2 are the same words, with the only difference being intonation and intent. (2) asserts, strongly, that the girl is telling the truth, and she really doesn't know you. (1) would likely be misunderstood, unless spoken very skillfully.

1 and 3 express the same meaning, which is quite subtle. It means "I thought that you did know me, so I'd like you to confirm that you haven't made a mistake."  This doesn't seem quite appropriate. You might use this if there was some doubt in your mind: "Don't you know me? I was in the same school as you, but two years above. I guess we didn't mix much with other classes."

But the context of your question suggests you are sure that she does know you, and you want to know the *reason* why she is denying it. Be careful, since you are accusing her of lying!  Do you *really* want to embarrass her in front of her friend??  If you do then "Why do you say that you don't know me?  (I'm your brother's best friend.)" expresses wonder and surprise and asks the question that you want answered.